# Installing SSL Certificate with Seafile

Tags: 14.04, apache2, ssl

I am attempting to install a certificate for Seafile and I'm confused as to where my 'config files' are per the instructions:

> Then modify your Apache configuration file.

This quote is from [here](https://manual.seafile.com/deploy/https_with_apache.html).

I searched and I got numerous hits on configs files for apache. How do I find where Seafile is hosted and my config file?

**EDIT**

To answer Owen Hines' question, I have seafile installed here:

```
root@seafile:/opt# ls -l
total 75628
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1432 Oct  4 19:43 cacert.pem
drwx------ 3 root root     4096 Oct  4 16:44 ccnet
drwx------ 2 root root     4096 Oct  4 16:44 conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct  4 17:14 logs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct  4 16:44 pids
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1679 Oct  4 19:42 privkey.pem
drwx------ 3 root root     4096 Oct  4 16:44 pro-data
drwx------ 8 root root     4096 Oct  4 16:44 seafile-data
drwxrwxr-x 8  500  500     4096 Aug 26 03:47 seafile-pro-server-5.1.11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 77399869 Oct  4 16:28 seafile-pro-server_5.1.11_x86-64.tar.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       25 Oct  4 16:40 seafile-server-latest -> seafile-pro-server-5.1.11
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Oct  4 16:40 seahub-data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps),

> On Ubuntu and Debian, Apache keeps its main configuration files within the **/etc/apache2** folder:
>
> There are a number of plain text files and some sub-directories in
>   this directory. These are some of the more useful locations to be
>   familiar with:
>
> - **apache2.conf**: This is the main configuration file for the server.
>     Almost all configuration can be done from within this file, although
>     it is recommended to use separate, designated files for simplicity.
>     This file will configure defaults and be the central point of access
>     for the server to read configuration details.
> - **ports.conf**: This file is
>     used to specify the ports that virtual hosts should listen on. Be sure
>     to check that this file is correct if you are configuring SSL.
> - **conf.d/**: This directory is used for controlling specific aspects of
>     the Apache configuration. For example, it is often used to define SSL
>     configuration and default security choices.
> - **sites-available/**: This
>     directory contains all of the virtual host files that define different
>     web sites. These will establish which content gets served for which
>     requests. These are available configurations, not active
>     configurations.
> - **sites-enabled/**: This directory establishes which
>     virtual host definitions are actually being used. Usually, this
>     directory consists of symbolic links to files defined in the
>     "sites-available" directory.
> - **mods-[enabled,available]/**: These
>     directories are similar in function to the sites directories, but they
>     define modules that can be optionally loaded instead. As you can see,
>     Apache configuration does not take place in a single monolithic file,
>     but instead happens through a modular design where new files can be
>     added and modified as needed.

As for where your SeaFile is hosted, it's wherever you extracted and ran it from.